# pendingintent.getservice not working properly

Tags: android, android-intent, android-pendingintent

I am trying to start a service using pendingintent and this is how i am trying

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub




                InfoLayout.setVisibility(LinearLayout.VISIBLE);
                mIntentService = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LocationService.class);
                mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(
                        MainActivity.this, 1, mIntentService, 0);

                locationrequest = LocationRequest.create();
                locationrequest.setInterval(10000 * 6);
                locationClient.requestLocationUpdates(locationrequest,
                        mPendingIntent);


                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Starting service",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });
```

I tried this code on 2.3.5 and it works fine, but when i tried this code on 4.4.2 my service is not at all starting. I am not understanding why this is happening. can some one please explain what is the wrong I am doing.

Thanks in advance:)

**EDIT**

```
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        // Toast.makeText(this, "in service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Location location = intent
                .getParcelableExtra(LocationClient.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED);

        db = new PhoneDatasource(this);
        db.open();
        contactlist = db.getAllContacts();
        db.close();

        if (location != null) {
            add = null;
            Constants.latitude = location.getLatitude();
            Constants.longitude = location.getLongitude();
        }
```

Comment: Can you post the applicable locationClient code that uses the PendingIntent you created (specifically requestLocationUpdates)? There appear to be several unresolved bugs in KitKat with regards to PendingIntents - perhaps your situation falls under one of those use cases.

Comment: @crazylpfan i have added the location client code

Comment: @user2386771 did you add service to AndroidManifest already. for me I always forgot it.

Comment: @zinuzoid i have added in manifest file.. it is actually working till 4.3 version. but in kitkat version it is not firing

Comment: Have you checked logcat to see if there are any error/warning messages or other clues there?

Comment: @hBrent no errors r warnings i am getting

Answer (score 2):

The answer might be on this page ("Location settings changes on Android 4.4"): https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/3467281

That is, in Android 4.4, you have to go to the new Location settings and explicitly turn it on (and configure the mode), or else no apps will be allowed to get any location information. Also, you need to be aware of the different location modes and how they will affect the ability of apps to get location information. Reading the linked page is crucial in 4.4.

Comment: @user2386771: If my answer works for you, please award me the bounty, as the grace period is ending very soon. Thanks.